# How to represent markdown properly with escaping and line breaks?

Tags: meteor, markdown

I'm currently trying to build a chat app, using the official markdown package as well as underscore's escape function, and my template contains something like this:

```
<span class="message-content">
    {{#markdown}}{{text}}{{/markdown}}
</span>
```

When I grab the text from the chat input box, I try to escape any HTML and then add in line breaks. `safeText` is then inserted into the database and displayed in the above template.

```
rawText = $("#chat-input-textbox").val();
safeText = _.escape(rawText).replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '\n');
```

The normal stuff like headings, italics, and bold looks okay. However, there are **two major problems**:

1. **Code escape issue** - With the following input:

   ````
   <script>alert("test")</script>
   ```
   alert('hello');
   ```
   This is _italics_!
   ````

   Everything looks fine, except the `alert('hello');` has become `alert(&#x27;hello&#x27;);` instead. The `<pre>` blocks aren't rendering the escaped characters, which makes sense. But the problem is, the underscore JS escape function escapes everything.
2. **SOLVED:** <s>**Line break Issue** - With the following input:</s>

   ```
   first
   second
   third
   ```

   I get `first second third` being displayed with no line breaks. I understand this could be a markdown thing. Since I believe you need an empty line between paragraphs to get linebreaks in markdown. But having the above behaviour would be the most ideal, anyone know how to do this?

**UPDATE** Line break issue has been solved by adding an extra `\n` to my regex. So now I'm making sure that *any* line break will be represented with at least two `\n` characters (i.e. `\n\n`).

Comment: can't you just use `{{{text}}}` instead of `{{text}}`?

Comment: @ChristianFritz it doesn't make a difference here.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [showdown docs](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) and the wiki article [they have on the topic](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/wiki/Markdown's-XSS-Vulnerability-%28and-how-to-mitigate-it%29).

The `marked` npm package, which is used by Telescope removes *disallowed*-tags. These include `<script>` of course. As the article I linked to above explains, there's still another problem with this:

```
<a href='javascript:alert("kidding! Im more the world domination kinda guy. Muhahahah")'>
  click me for world peace!
</a>
```

Which isn't prevented by marked. I'd follow the advice of the author and use a HTML sanitation library. Like [OWASP's ESAPI](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-js/) or [Caja's html-sanitizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitizer). Both of these project's seem outdated dough. I also found a showdown extension for it called [showdown-xss-filter](https://github.com/VisionistInc/showdown-xss-filter). So my advice is to write your own helper, and use showdown-xss-filter.